# how can you validate an email as invalid when the email don't have the .com in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering, can you validate an email without the .com as invalid in Flutter

```
Example:
johnny@gmail.com = true
johnny@johnny    = false
```

Comment: Have you tried to google search about this make sure to search on google if you not get answer then only ask Question here.

Comment: @VishalParmar I tried to search it and I found someone else stack, but the regex doesn't validate if the email have or don't have the .com. So I want to make sure by asking a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I use for my email validators is this:

```
String? validateEmail(String email) {
    const String pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    final RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
    if (email.isEmpty || !regex.hasMatch(email)) {
      return 'Invalid email';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

hope it helps.

```
Example:
johnny@gmail.com = true
johnny@johnny.co    = true
johnny@johnny    = false
johnny@    = false
johnny    = false
johnny@johnny.c    = false
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but your code is the same as me

Comment: can you add the code, so that we can see and understand it better

Comment: I found the problem, my regex is slight different than yours, and when I use your regex it solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code you can import this class in to the page you want u can just validate any String like following

```
extension EmailValidator on String {
     bool isValidEmail() {
        return RegExp(
           r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)| 
    (\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a- 
      zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')
      .hasMatch(this);
                     }
               }
```

eg:`if(anyString.isValidEmail()) { print("Valid")}`